# Find and replace in files; regular expressions and visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to replace all class declarations in a list of files using the following regex:

Find:

```
public class (.*)
```

Replace with:

```
[SomeAttribute]\npublic class $1 : MustInheritFromThisThingy<WithSome, More, Stuff>
```

It works, but Visual Studio decides to put a line break after the class name.
Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: why are you using capturing group in first place when you are rewriting the same thing using `$1`?

Comment: Replace the dot with `[^\r\n]`. The dot matches CR symbol, too.

Comment: @rock321987 I have absolutely zero experience with regex, so I don't know any better ;)

Comment: anyhow you can try what @WiktorStribiżew suggested

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew make an answer of your comment so I can upvote it.

Comment: I am traveling now, and it is very difficult to type with my daughter sleeping on my right arm :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the dot with `[^\r\n]`. The dot matches CR symbol, too.

Use

```
public class ([^\r\n]*)
```